# Splitting sentences from prose

Tags: python, regex, parsing, text, nlp

I am trying to split on sentences, and also preserve dialogue markers.  So a sentence like

> “Dirty, Mr. Jones? Look at my shoes! Not a speck on them.”  This is a non-dialogue sentence!

Should return the list

```
[
    "“Dirty, Mr. Jones?”",
    "“Look at my shoes!”",
    "“Not a speck on them.”",
    "This is a non-dialogue sentence!"
]
```

I’m struggling with preserving the end-of-sentence punctuation while preserving the period on `Mr.`. I am also struggling with inserting the quotation marks, as currently the returned list is `['“Dirty, Mr. Jones”', '“Look at my shoes”', '“Not a speck on them”', '“”', 'This is a non-dialogue sentence', '']` and I don’t know why I’m getting the two empty elements. How can I fix these problems?

Here is my code (eventually this will parse the whole book but for now I’m testing it on one phrase):

```
def get_all_sentences(corpus):

  sentences_in_paragraph = []

  dialogue = False
  dialogue_sentences = ""
  other_sentences = ""

  example_paragraph = "“Dirty, Mr. Jones? Look at my shoes! Not a speck on them.”  This is a non-dialogue sentence!"

  example_paragraph = example_paragraph.replace("\n", "") # remove newline

  for character in example_paragraph:
    if character == "“":
        dialogue = True
        continue
    if character == "”":
        dialogue = False
        continue

    if dialogue:
        dialogue_sentences += character
    else:
        other_sentences += character

  sentences_in_paragraph  = list(map(lambda x: "“" + x.strip() + "”", re.split("(?<!Mr|Ms)(?<!Mrs)[.!?]", dialogue_sentences))) 
  sentences_in_paragraph += list(map(lambda x: x.strip(), re.split("(?<!Mr|Ms)(?<!Mrs)[.!?]", other_sentences)))

  print(sentences_in_paragraph)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add `print` statements to show the intermediate steps, you can see where the problem is introduced:

```
sentence_splitter_regex = "(?<!Mr|Ms)(?<!Mrs)[.!?]"
dialogue_sentences_list = re.split(sentence_splitter_regex, dialogue_sentences)
print("dialogue sentences:", dialogue_sentences_list)
other_sentences_list = re.split(sentence_splitter_regex, other_sentences)
print("other sentences:", other_sentences_list)

sentences_in_paragraph  = list(map(lambda x: "“" + x.strip() + "”", dialogue_sentences_list)) 
sentences_in_paragraph += list(map(lambda x: x.strip(), other_sentences_list))
```

```
dialogue sentences ['Dirty, Mr. Jones', ' Look at my shoes', ' Not a speck on them', '']
other sentences ['    This is a non-dialogue sentence', '']
```

The `re.split` is leaving an empty element at the end. You can fix this by processing the result using a `for` comprehension with an `if` clause to not include empty strings:

```
[sentence for sentence in sentences_with_whitespace if sentence.strip() != '']
```

You should put this code inside a new function `split_sentences_into_list` to keep your code organized. It also makes sense to move the `.strip()` processing from `get_all_sentences` into this function, by changing the first part of the `for` comprehension to `sentence.strip()`.

```
import re

def split_sentences_into_list(sentences_string):
    sentence_splitter_regex = "(?<!Mr|Ms)(?<!Mrs)[.!?]"
    sentences_with_whitespace = re.split(sentence_splitter_regex, sentences_string)
    return [sentence.strip() for sentence in sentences_with_whitespace if sentence.strip() != '']

def get_all_sentences(corpus):
    sentences_in_paragraph = []

    dialogue = False
    dialogue_sentences = ""
    other_sentences = ""

    example_paragraph = "“Dirty, Mr. Jones? Look at my shoes! Not a speck on them.”    This is a non-dialogue sentence!"

    example_paragraph = example_paragraph.replace("\n", "") # remove newline

    for character in example_paragraph:
        if character == "“":
            dialogue = True
            continue
        if character == "”":
            dialogue = False
            continue

        if dialogue:
            dialogue_sentences += character
        else:
            other_sentences += character

    dialogue_sentences_list = split_sentences_into_list(dialogue_sentences)
    other_sentences_list = split_sentences_into_list(other_sentences)

    sentences_in_paragraph  = list(map(lambda x: "“" + x + "”", dialogue_sentences_list)) 
    sentences_in_paragraph += other_sentences_list

    print(sentences_in_paragraph)

get_all_sentences(None)
```

This has the expected output:

```
['“Dirty, Mr. Jones”', '“Look at my shoes”', '“Not a speck on them”', 'This is a non-dialogue sentence']
```

By the way, standard Python style is to use `for` comprehensions instead of `map` and `lambda` when possible. It would make your code shorter in this case:

```
# from
sentences_in_paragraph  = list(map(lambda x: "“" + x + "”", dialogue_sentences_list)) 
# to
sentences_in_paragraph  = ["“" + x + "”" for x in dialogue_sentences_list]
```